# Asp.Net Menu not rendering for only one developer

Tags: asp.net, menu

We have an ASP.Net menu that works fine for everyone except for one developer.

We verified that the source code on his machine is identical to everyone else's. We checked the generated HTML and verified that it is not a display problem. We stepped through the code and made sure that the menu control was set to visible in PreRender.

The really strange thing is that this problem has only been occurring for him in three separate branches. Yet this problem has never been reported in QA or production. We also checked/verified that this problem occurs across all three major browsers.

We cannot show you our code due to the nature of this application. If anyone has ever experienced a similar problem or knows a resolution we appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the dev workstation is polluted in some way. Either there's something cached or a system setting somewhere preventing this.

I'd say that if this problem can't be reproduced on any other machine/VM/customer, then don't worry about it.

Have you distilled the problem with a sample app/menu, or is it just in that one particular application?